# posting x-www-form-urlencoded with javascript

Tags: javascript, request, httpclient

I have been searching all over the web without any result.
I want to send a post request to a server with x-www-form-urlencoded headers.
Here is my code:

```
function makeFormEncoder(hash){
  return function(key) {
    return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(hash[key]);
  };
}


function getAccessToken() {
// eg,
// curl -X POST -i -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
//     "https://api.usergrid.com/management/token" \
//     -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=XXXX&client_secret=shhhh'
//
//
// {"access_token":"BAADBEEF","expires_in":604800,"application":"uuid-here"}


  var formValues = {
        'grant_type': 'password',
        'username': appSvcs.username,
        'password': appSvcs.password
      },
      pairs = Object.keys(formValues).map(makeFormEncoder(formValues)),
      headers = {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      url = getAppServicesUrl() + '/token',
      req = new Request(url, 'POST', headers, pairs.join('&')),
      exchange = httpClient.send(req);
}

var res = getAccessToken();
console.log(res);
```

When I run the above code I see the below error:

> functions.js:322 Uncaught ReferenceError: httpClient is not defined
>       at getAccessToken (functions.js:322)
>       at HTMLInputElement. (functions.js:333)
>       at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-2.2.0.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (jquery-2.2.0.min.js:3) getAccessToken @ functions.js:322 (anonymous) @ functions.js:333
>   dispatch @ jquery-2.2.0.min.js:3 r.handle @ jquery-2.2.0.min.js:3

Thank you for your time!